# Find Inverse of ideal $I= \langle 3, 1+2\sqrt{-5} \rangle$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Question- Find Inverse of ideal $I = \langle 3, 1 + 2\sqrt{-5} \rangle$ of $O_K$ (ring of integers of algebraic number field $K$), where $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$.

First of all can $I$ be simplified more than $I = \langle 3, 1 + 2\sqrt{-5} \rangle = \langle 3, 2 - 2\sqrt{-5} \rangle$ which is not much help.

Now if because  $I$ is a prime ideal then, $I^{-1} = I' =  {\alpha \in K :\ \alpha I \subseteq O_K}$.

While attempting to find $I'$, I started by letting $x + y{\sqrt-5} \in K$ and then when proceeded, what I got is $3x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $3y, 11y \in \mathbb{Z}$ but this says that no rational $y$ can exist. So obviously I did something wrong. I guess my answer should be in terms of $I$, can somebody help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- $I=\langle 3,1-\sqrt{-5}\rangle$.
- If $J=\langle 3,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$, then prove that $IJ=\langle 3\rangle$.
- Deduce that $I^{-1}$ is $J$ times a principal fractional ideal.

Comment: For First hint- I am getting $I=\langle 3,2(1-\sqrt{-5})\rangle$,   but $\langle 3,1-\sqrt{-5}\rangle \neq \langle 3,2(1-\sqrt{-5})\rangle $

Comment: @Bhaskar: $1-\sqrt{-5}=(1+2\sqrt{-5})-3\sqrt{-5}\in I$, because $3\in I$ and $1+2\sqrt{-5}\in I$.

Comment: Ohh yeah, now i got it,  because obviously $\langle 3,2(1-2\sqrt{-5})\rangle \subset \langle 3,1-2\sqrt{-5}\rangle$ and for other inclusion  $3(1-\sqrt{-5})-2(1-\sqrt{-5})=1-\sqrt{-5}$ . Thanks.

Comment: Obviously because $O_K$ here is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Comment: Good! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: In another question I am trying to find inverse of $I= \langle1+\sqrt{-5}, 1-\sqrt{-5}\rangle$. In this case it seemed nicer to square $I$ but I got $I^2= \langle6, -2(2+ \sqrt{-5}), -2(2- \sqrt{-5}) \rangle$ which I do not think is equal to any principal integral ideal. Any other approach for it?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth: Try to prove that $I^2=\langle 2\rangle$.